# Output a list of duplicate values ID's and non duplicate values using Python

Tags: python, pandas, opencsv

I have a huge dataset held in a **csv** file which holds 2 columns in excel of data which I need to print out the row ID of which ones **have the same** results (regardless of the order of numbers) and another list of results that are **not the same**. Some cells have more than 2 integers in them. I am trying to use Python to do this, I've also read around and Panda seems to be the way forwards. Please note I am new to Python and cannot seem to find a simple script to do this (only ones that delete duplicates).

**So for example the required output would give me**

`Duplicated Row ID's: 1, 3`.

`Unique Row ID's: 2, 4`.

```
 A        B            C
ID      Col1         Col2
-----------------------------
1    ["1", "3"]   ["3", "1"]        
2    ["1", "2"]   ["9", "2"]
3    ["8", "0"]   ["0", "8"]
4    ["3", "7"]   ["1", "3"]
```

Comment: Don't share the screenshot instead share us the dataframe in form of text.

Comment: There is `MultiIndex` in columns? What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: @T.C - Use `df = pd.read_csv(file)`

Comment: @T.C - Can you send me link for chatroom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if necessary convert string repr to lists:

```
import ast

df['ColA'] = df['ColA'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['ColB'] = df['ColB'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Then sorting both columns lists and compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), last filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `~` is for invert mask:

```
m = df['ColA'].apply(sorted).eq(df['ColB'].apply(sorted))
dup = df.loc[m, 'ID']
print (dup)
0    1
2    3
Name: ID, dtype: int64

un = df.loc[~m, 'ID']
print (un)
1    2
3    4
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

For improve performance is possible convert lists to DataFrames and compare, only necessary same lengths of lists in both columns and in all rows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df['ColA'].tolist(), axis=1), index=df.index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df['ColB'].tolist(), axis=1), index=df.index)
print (df1)
   0  1
0  1  3
1  1  2
2  0  8
3  3  7

m = df1.eq(df2).all(axis=1)
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: may I ask, I don't necessarily want to hardcode any integers in the code do I, as the actual dataset I have, is millions of lines long, so will the above still be ok?

Comment: @T.C - hmm, in columns `B, C` are lists? If yes, all lists has same length `2` in both columns, in all DataFrame rows?

Comment: is it possible to alter this script easily to only show exact matches in the 2 columns? i.e. the number in the exact same order?